# How to rebuild all grid items in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, bloc

I have a *dashboard*, represented by grid, that supposed to delete item on long press event (using [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_bloc)), but it deletes last item instead of selected. All debug prints show, that needed element actually removed from list, but view layer still keeps it.

My build function code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double pyxelRatio = MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * pyxelRatio;

    return BlocProvider(
      bloc: _bloc,
        child: BlocBuilder<Request, DataState>(
        bloc: _bloc,
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is EmptyDataState) {
            print("Uninit");
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          if (state is ErrorDataState) {
            print("Error");
            return Center(
              child: Text('Something went wrong..'),
            );
          }
          if (state is LoadedDataState) {
            print("empty: ${state.contracts.isEmpty}");
            if (state.contracts.isEmpty) {
              return Center(
                child: Text('Nothing here!'),
              );
            } else{
              print("items count: ${state.contracts.length}");              
              print("-------");
              for(int i = 0; i < state.contracts.length; i++){
                if(state.contracts[i].isFavorite)print("fut:${state.contracts[i].name} id:${state.contracts[i].id}");
              }
              print("--------");  

              List<Widget> testList = new List<Widget>();
              for(int i = 0; i < state.contracts.length; i++){
                if(state.contracts[i].isFavorite) testList.add(
                  InkResponse(
                  enableFeedback: true,
                  onLongPress: (){
                    showShortToast();
                    DashBLOC dashBloc = BlocProvider.of<DashBLOC>(context);
                    dashBloc.dispatch(new UnfavRequest(state.contracts[i].id));
                  },
                  onTap: onTap,
                  child:DashboardCardWidget(state.contracts[i])
                  )
              );
              }
              return GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: width >= 900 ? 2 : 1,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  children: testList
              );
            }
          }
      })
    );
  }
```

[full class code](https://pastebin.com/dxs8tdpF) and [dashboard bloc](https://pastebin.com/cqx7Yzzm)

Looks like grid rebuilds itself, but don't rebuild its tiles. 
How can I completely update grid widget with all its subwidgets?

> p.s i've spent two days fixing it, pls help

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use a `GridView.builder`constructor to specify a build function which will update upon changes in the list of items, so when any update occur in your data the `BlocBuilder` will trigger the build function inside your`GridView`.

I hope this example makes it more clear.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Test(),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  List<int> testList = List<int>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      testList.add(i);
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        //Here we can remove an item from the list and using setState
        //or BlocBuilder will rebuild the grid with the new list data
        onPressed: () => setState(() {testList.removeLast();})
      ),
      body: GridView.builder(
        // You must specify the items count of your grid
        itemCount: testList.length,
        // You must use the GridDelegate to specify row item count
        // and spacing between items
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 5,
          childAspectRatio: 1.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
          mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
        ),
        // Here you can build your desired widget which will rebuild
        // upon changes using setState or BlocBuilder
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Text(
            testList[index].toString(),
            textScaleFactor: 1.3,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is always sending the last value of int i.

So instead of

```
for(int i = 0; i < state.contracts.length; i++){
            if(state.contracts[i].isFavorite) testList.add(
              InkResponse(
              enableFeedback: true,
              onLongPress: (){
                showShortToast();
                DashBLOC dashBloc = BlocProvider.of<DashBLOC>(context);
                dashBloc.dispatch(new UnfavRequest(state.contracts[i].id));
              },
              onTap: onTap,
              child:DashboardCardWidget(state.contracts[i])
              )
          );
```

Do

```
          List<Widget> testList = new List<Widget>();

          state.contracts.forEach((contract){
            if(contract.isFavorite) testList.add(
              InkResponse(
              enableFeedback: true,
              onLongPress: (){
                showShortToast();
                DashBLOC dashBloc = BlocProvider.of<DashBLOC>(context);
                dashBloc.dispatch(new UnfavRequest(contract.id));
              },
              onTap: onTap,
              child:DashboardCardWidget(contract)
              )
          ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it actually rebuilds? I'm just don't understand why you use the State with **BLoC**. Even if you use the **State** you should call the **setState()** method to update the widget with new data. 
On my opinion the best solution to you will be to try to inherit your widget from **StatelessWidget** and call the **dispatch(new UpdateRequest());** in the **DashBLOC** constructor.

Also always keep in mind this link about the `bloc`, there are lots of examples:
https://felangel.github.io/bloc/#/

Answer (score 0):

just give children a key

```
 return  GridView.builder(
                itemCount: children.length,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(3),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    key: ValueKey(children.length+index),                       
                  );
                });
```